How do I implement App Check with Flutter for Android release?
I've been trying for a few days to implement App Check using Play Integrity (since SafetyNet, which is all I could get to work before is deprecated) but no matter what I do, I can only get it to work in development using the debug token, and not in release. The official documentation seems to stop after saying how to set it up for development/debug. Whenever I try to sign in on a release version, I get the error: Firebase App Check token is invalid. With an unknown/null key. Has anyone been able to get this to work recently?

flutter doctor -v returns no issues
all packages and dart are up-to-date
I'm calling await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate in main.dart, tried with and without specifying androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity, I've confirmed this is running prior to login attempt
I've added both SHA-256 fingerprints from the release keytool terminal command, using the created keystore, and the signing key from Google Play Console
signingConfigs is in app/build.gradle with the keystore properties, and the release buildTypes is present as well
All SHA values are present in the firebase project settings, and google-services.json is up-to-date in the app
firebase_app_check is added and up-to-date
The Google Cloud project is linked in Google Play console, and the Integrity API is enabled in the Google Cloud project
app/build.gradle includes org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version, implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.8.0', implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.3.0' among other implementations I've tried before... HOWEVER, "Integreate with the Play Integrity API" isn't checked off in App Integrity on the Google Play Console for some reason
android/build.gradle contains buildscript with google-services, gradle, and kotlin
I'm using a Pixel 8 emulator API 34 Android 14.0, the device is supported in the Play console


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Play Integrity when integrated with App Check checks that the app is an authentic untampered app and that the device is an authentic untampered device.
To verify that the app is an authentic untampered app, you must download the app from the Play Store. It uses the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint from the Google Play Store to validate that the app was signed with the appropriate signing key. In this case, it should be a PLAY_RECOGNIZED verdict.
To verify that the device is a genuine authentic device, it should run the latest version of Google Play Services and be a real device, not an emulator. Also the device should be using a signed distribution of the Android OS, some other ROMs that may be loaded will likely not support Play Integrity. In this case it would be MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY verdict.
Based on the information provided above, it seems that you are running an emulator which would fail the genuine device check. I would suggest that you obtain a real device to test with and then obtain your app from the Google Play Store to validate that the appropriate keys are signed.
If you wind up purchasing an Android device, you would also need to make sure that it contains Google Play on the device and not a downloaded version of Google Play from an APK mirror. Some devices have alternative attestation providers instead of Google Play (Samsung supports Knox and Play Integrity, Huawei only supports Huawei Safety Detect).
With Play Integrity for App Check, the highest level of security was designated since that can prevent the most abuse of your services.
If you feel that this level of protection is too much, you are always able to implement a custom provider using Play Integrity (or another attestation provider of your choice) and lower the protection level. For instance, in your case, you may want to lower the protection to UNRECOGNIZED if you do not plan on getting the app from Google Play and then validating the certificate digest yourself. And if you want to run on an emulator you could also lower the security to MEETS_VIRTUAL_INTEGRITY. Both of these will open your app to large amounts of abuse since having Virtual integrity means that folks can grab a version of your app from Play and script abuse using the emulators. If you only check application integrity, you would need to be certain that the digest you are verifying is valid and matches your known digests, otherwise, folks could download a mirrored version of your app and have some of the binary components changed to bypass your applications intended uses.
I hope this helps explain the Play Integrity API and some of its security features with App Check.
